Robot Frame work close the file upload window
In my automation I am using the below code to upload a file using robot , which is working
Click Element  ${import_campaign_button} 
Choose File    ${import_filechooser}    ${path}${testdata}${file_name}


Problem is I can't use the second element without clicking on the first elelment ${import_campaign_button} . After this operation , the file browser window is still in browser
I tried the below ways to get rid of that
Press Keys    None    ESC or Press Keys    ${import_filechooser}    ESC
but none of them were successful , I am able to proceed with other tests even though the window is open , but I would like to close it before proceeding
Any suggestions to fix this issue..? or do I need to use other options like sikkuli or pywinauto for upload..?
tried steps are explanied in question

SeleniumLibrary doesn't require you to click the input field, instead the Choose File keyword should be directly used on the input field. Have you tried checking that the page doesn't have a valid object with locator //input[@type='file']?

Thats not working out , as clicking on the first element is making the other element showing up in DOM


You can try executing a JavaScript snippet to close the file dialog.

Click Element  ${import_campaign_button}
Choose File    ${import_filechooser}    ${path}${testdata}${file_name}
Execute JavaScript  window.close()


If the file dialog opens in a new window, you can switch to that
window and close it.

Click Element  ${import_campaign_button}
Choose File    ${import_filechooser}    ${path}${testdata}${file_name}
Switch Window  NEW
Close Window
Switch Window  MAIN


You can use the AutoItLibrary in Robot Framework to handle the file
dialog.
If the above methods don't work, you can indeed use Sikuli or
Pywinauto to handle the file upload.     These tools are designed to
interact with GUI elements and can be more reliable for such tasks.

